# Is there a Email Service from GMail?

Tags: smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I am in a need of sending emails using user's Gmail account
programatically.

I know, I can achieve this using SMTP and PHPMailer.

But for this, user have to [enable less secure apps in his account security settings](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps). Which is little bit annoying or users may not accept this.

How can I create some app/account (like Mandrill) and get some common credentials for Gmail and use them to send emails from PHPMailer.

Is there such a provision from Gmail?

**Note:** I own a domain and G-Suite account.

Answer (score 0):

This is largely untrue.

a) You don't have to enable less secure apps; you can use XOAUTH2 authentication which avoids that requirement, and is supported by PHPMailer. Read the docs, wiki, and examples for how to do that, though being based on OAuth means it's difficult and unpleasant to implement, but it does work. It's annoying that gmail labelled this feature in the way they have, as it does not represent a less secure configuration anyway - ultimately even XOAUTH2 is protected only by a username and password.

b) Even if you do enable less secure apps, it only applies to you as the sender, not to anyone to whom you send email, so users are not in a position to even know that it's happening.

You can't send using arbitrary from addresses through gmail, only your account address and any preconfigured aliases. That's a gmail limitation, and you may prefer to use a delivery service like sendgrid to avoid that limitation (though you will still be subject to SPF & DMARC restrictions).

Note that gmail and gsuite are not the same thing; gsuite generally has fewer features and has more limitations, despite being the paid-for option.

Comment: I am already using PHPMailer 6.0 with XOAUTH2. Still I get the error, `SMTP connect failed`. When I googled, I found only the solution of enabling less secure apps. Could you please share any links that provides guide for some sample implementation using XOAUTH2?

Comment: Then it's likely it's failing for some other reason, such as your ISP blocking outbound SMTP. The troubleshooting guide linked from your error message will tell you how to diagnose it, and the docs, wiki, and examples on the github project site has lots more - I can't give you more links right now because github is down.

Comment: How do I actually send from an alias with this method? It defaults to my main account, regardless of what I put in the "from" section - which is a valid alias